# Swift iOS: Determine if bezier path intersects with UIView frame?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I’ve created a custom UIView that draws a UIBezierPath, assigns it to a CAShapeLayer, and then masks it to the UIView’s root layer. Now what I’m trying to do is determine if a different UIView is intersecting (or overlapping) any part of the bezier path in that custom view, using the following code:

```
    let customView = … // define UICustomView

    let purpleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 500, width: 100, height: 50))
    purpleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    self.view.addSubview(purpleView)
    
    if purpleView.frame.intersects((customView.shapeLayer.path?.boundingBoxOfPath)!) == true { 
        print("Overlapping")
    } else {
        print("Not overlapping")
    }
```

The only problem is that it only returns true if the purpleView is at the top left of the partial square. The placement below returns false:

(I want it to return true if it’s overlapping any of the green, and false otherwise. I’ve only drawn 3 sides of the square and intentionally left the fill empty)

[image]

The following is the code for the custom view

```
class CustomView : UIView {

private var _path : UIBezierPath!
public let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self._setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self._setup()
}

private func _setup() {
    self._createSquare()
}

private func _createSquare() { 
    self._path = UIBezierPath()
    self._path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    self._path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.size.height))
    self._path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height))
    self._path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 0.0))
    //self._path.close()
    
    
    
    self.shapeLayer.path = self._path.cgPath
    self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor 
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.shapeLayer.fillColor = nil 
    self.layer.mask = self.shapeLayer   
}
}
```

Is there a way to make this happen? I realize using the frame.intersects() function might not be the right approach.

Comment: What is `demoView`? Is that supposed to be `customView`?

Comment: demoView is supposed to be customView. It’s been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up coordinate spaces. `boundBoxOfPath` is in `CustomView`'s coordinate space, whereas `purpleView.frame` is in the coordinate space of `self.view`. You should only compare paths when they are in the same coordinate space. The various [`convert`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicoordinatespace/1622564-convert) methods in `UICoordinateSpace` can be used to convert between coordinate spaces.

```
if let pathBounds = customView.shapeLayer.path?.boundingBoxOfPath,
   self.view.convert(purpleView.frame, to: customView).intersects(pathBounds) {
    print("Overlapping")
} else {
    print("Not overlapping")
}
```

Note that this will check if the two rectangles overlap. It will return true for cases like this too:

[image]

The green "rectangle" *completely covers* the purple rectangle, and that is also a kind of intersection.

If you just want to check if the purple rectangle intersects the green *lines*, you can create a new path from the green path, such that, when filled with green, the result is the same as if you *stroked* the green path. See [`copy(strokingWithWidth:lineCap:lineJoin:miterLimit:transform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2427133-copy).

Then, you create a rectangular path from `purpleView.frame`, and check if the new path and the rectangular path intersects, using `CGPath.intersects`.

```
let purpleViewPath = CGPath(rect: self.view.convert(purpleView.frame, to: customView), transform: nil)
if let path = customView.shapeLayer.path?.copy(
    strokingWithWidth: customView.shapeLayer.lineWidth,

    // these are the default values for a CGShapeLayer.
    // you can also try converting the values from the corresponding properties in CGShapeLayer
    lineCap: .butt,
    lineJoin: .miter,
    miterLimit: 10
),
   purpleViewPath.intersects(path, using: .evenOdd) {
    print("Overlapping")
} else {
    print("Not overlapping")
}
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly. Admittedly, this is difficult for me to understand, but I’m pretty sure I’m in a bit over my head on this. At least now I can dissect the code and find some tutorials to help me better understand what’s going on. Thank you for your help!